# Finding the appropriate CNN Model Architecture and Parameters

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently creating a CNN model that classifies whether the font is `Arial`, `Verdana`, `Times New Roman` and `Georgia`. All in all there are `16` classes since I considered also detecting whether the font is `regular`, `bold`, `italics` or `bold italics`. So `4 fonts * 4 styles = 16 classes`.

The data that I have used in my training are the following:

```
 Training data set : 800 image patches of 256 * 256 dimension (50 for each class)
 Validation data set : 320 image patches of 256 * 256 dimension (20 for each class)
 Testing data set : 160 image patches of 256 * 256 dimension (10 for each class)
```

Below is the sample screenshot of my data:

[image]

Below is my initial code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle


image_width = 256
image_height = 256

train_path = 'font_model_data/train'
valid_path =  'font_model_data/valid'
test_path = 'font_model_data/test'


train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(image_width, image_height), classes=['1','2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16'], batch_size = 16)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(image_width, image_height), classes=['1','2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16'], batch_size = 16)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(image_width, image_height), classes=['1','2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16'], batch_size = 160)


 imgs, labels = next(train_batches)

 #CNN model
 model = Sequential([
     Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(image_width, image_height, 3)),
     Flatten(),
     Dense(16, activation='softmax'),
 ])

 print(model.summary())

 model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
 model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch = 50, validation_data= valid_batches, validation_steps = 20, epochs = 1, verbose = 2)

 model_pickle = open('cnn_font_model.pickle', 'wb')
 pickle.dump(model, model_pickle)
 model_pickle.close()
 print('Training Done.')

 test_imgs, test_labels = next(test_batches)

 predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps = 160, verbose = 2)
 print(predictions)
```

Can anyone suggest how will I know the right network architecture and parameters to get the optimal accuracy? How should I start tweaking my network?

Comment: Did you think about two output layers? One for style, one for font? Such architecture may reduce output to 8 class. Will be interesting compare these two approaches :)

Comment: @viceriel --> Thanks, but I dont know how to encode my training labels. I am using ImageDataGenerator and it automatically create 16 class for my training data. I dont know how to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to choose Network you need to segmentize the image tile into subtitles with characters and feed to the following architecture...

```
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = XXX,
                     epochs = XX,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = XXX)
from keras.models import load_model
classifier.save('your_classifier.h5')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "segmentize the image tile into subtitles". Divide my image patch into characters?

Comment: This answer is unclear. Why are you suggesting that the image needs to be segmented somehow? Also, your answer does not fit the info in the question. For instance, your input size is `64 x 64 x 3`, while actual images are `256 x 256` (I don't know about color channels). Or, you are predicting 2 output classes with sigmoid + binary cross-entropy, while the OP states they have 16 classes.

Comment: This example is is made for digit and non digit classification which have binary classification in your case you can add softmax to it. And why I prefer segmentation is during convolution and pooling process the it will only focus on the the characters select featured. It's working my digit and non digit classification